# QGIS - atlas print composer how to display mutiple values when adding attribute table?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, expression, atlas, statistics

[image]

I have this attribute table. I locked my atlas generator by county. For each, I want the statistics of all the cities that are in each county. For example :
If the page of SICARIO is showed I want :

- Trapani
- Palerme
- Catane

Like so :
[image]

For instance, I achieved showing just the statistics for one city for each county using this expression

`"city_name" || ' : '|| round((  "people_ok" *100)/  "total_of_people") || '% of people are ok and'|| round((  "people_not_ok" *100)/  "total_of_people") || '% are not'`  , like that :

[image]

**How can I do to tell QGIS to show ALL the cities that belong to SICARIO ?**

While knowing that:

- for SICARIO I have to display 3 cities
- for RADEON 2 cities
- for TUNEM 3 cities

It's unclear to me why when adding the attribute table, only the first line that matches is displayed.

Comment: If you use an atlas, you have a coverage layer. In a case like yours, it would make sense to have a coverage polygon layer for the counties and a separate (point or polygon) layer for the cities. Then you could identify the features (cities) within the current atlas feature. This is not the case, if I understand you correctly? You have only one layer and want to do this from there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have everything on one layer (as it seems to be the case), you should use aggregate functions and filter the aggregated `city_names` by `conty_name` to create an array with all cities in a county using `array_agg()` function. From this array, loop through each element (city) to get the respective attribute values for the fiels `people_ok` and `people_not_ok`.

**Edit**: I tested your sample project and had to make only small adjustments. Use a text layout element, not an attribute table layout element, to introduce this text, as you don't really need an attribute table element for this, you use it to create a text, containing different attribute values concatenated. HOwever, the expression also works if you intreroduce it in the attribute table layout element.

Use the expression below:

[image]

```
with_variable(
    'county',
    county_nam,
    array_to_string(
        array_foreach(
            array_agg (
                city_name, 
                filter:="county_nam"=@county
            ),
            @element 
            || ': ' ||
            attribute(
                get_feature('counties_cities','city_name', @element),
                'people_ok'
            )
            || ' % of people are OK and ' ||
            attribute(
                get_feature('counties_cities','city_name', @element),
                'people_not'
            )
            || ' % are not'
        ),
        delimiter:= '\n' 
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @Babel ! Unfortunately it does not work for me cause I have to introduce the statistics with an attribute table as I have parent/children relation. It will not work with inserting a label as on my locked layer for my atlas does not have this information : "people_ok","people_not_ok"...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your settings correctly. I looked at your attribute table and there you have this information. I can only answer based on what information you provide. Also, I don't understand what you mean by "locked" layer. You should probably share your project with sample/dummy data to see what you have. Otherwise, it is just guessing in the dark.

Comment: you are right it is not easy to explain so I made a link with my project and my layers in it : https://we.tl/t-WGlj7hOKah. It will be more clear. Nevertheless, thanks for your help

Comment: See updated answer - it works with your project/data.

Comment: I do know how to thanks you @Babel ! It works so well !!